# how to calculate the discrete number of steps per feature of dataset

Tags: r, matlab, dataset, classification, discretization

I have been looking for a way to calculate the minimum number of samples required *Ne(min)* to train a classification model when the dataset is not normally distributed. A research paper suggests the following :

> if the data are not normally distributed, an exponential relationship between d and N will be
>   assumed and the number of samples that are required may be as plentiful as:
>                      **Ne(min) = Dsteps^d**
>   where **Dsteps** is the discrete number of steps per feature.
>   d: dimension of the dataset.
>   ....
>   It
>   is useful to think of a histogram approach to understand this relationship. **If we want to construct a histogram from data with at least one sample in each bin and with *Dsteps* discrete steps per feature, we will require at least *Dsteps*^d samples.**
>   The number of samples required to model the data accurately is in this case an exponential function of d.

I will be very grateful if someone can help me to get/calculate this measure: *the discrete number of steps per feature*.
An explanation with R or Matlab code would be very helpful. Thank you :D

**Edit:**
Paper reference: Christiaan Maarten Van Der Walt: Data Measure that Characterises Classification Problems, 2008.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan the features are continuous variables, and apparently it must be one measure for the whole dataset, not for each feature.

Comment: There is information missing. `d` is the number of columns in your feature matrix and you want to determine `Ne(min)` but there is no information given about `Dsteps`. You may want to have a closer look in the research paper (and also provide the reference here...)

Comment: @max, yes d is the number of features; and here is the link of the paper: [https://repository.up.ac.za/bitstream/handle/2263/27624/dissertation.pdf] (page 60). Thank you for the help :)